# JS countdown multiple times on page (won't display with getElementsByClassName)

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I took some JS code from w3 to create a countdown. (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp)

Because I want to display the countdown multiple times on one page I changed the `getElementById("demo")` to > `getElementsByClassName("demo")`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Nothing shows up. Why is that and how can I display the same counter multiple times? I tried some things but nothing worked out. This is my code:

html

```
<p class="demo"></p>
```

js

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`. (A bunch of HTML elements). You'll have to iterate through them.

Comment: replace the `document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML` with `document.querySelector(".demo").innerHTML`

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight so I would need a for loop or soemthing? I am not capable of doing this. Is there an easy fix to achieve my goal? I also tried adding multiple IDs `getElementById("demo demotwo demothree")` but that won't work as well...

Comment: @Warkus I am confused. So you want multiple elements or one element?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili I tried your solution but it shows the timer just once https://jsfiddle.net/5y17c2bd/1/  - I want the same timer to be visible multiple times on one page - lets say 5 times (top right, bottom, middle whatever haha) - so yes multiple elemets (but same class i guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ShanieMoonlight mentioned you need to iterate over the HTMLCollection. You can easily do it with minimal adjustments. E.g. when you use the spread-operator the forEach-function will be available.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("demo")].forEach(e => e.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("demo")].forEach(e=>e.innerHTML = "EXPIRED");
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="demo"></p>

<p class="demo"></p>

<p class="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You might want to store the results of `[...document.getElementsByClassName("demo")]` outside of the interval so it won't unnecessarily look for the elements again for each second.

Comment: Thank you very much - much appreciated!

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I don't know how to do that - is it very computationally intensive or what would be the reason for doing?

Comment: @Warkus Place `var demos = [...document.getElementsByClassName("demo")];` above the interval. Then use `demos.forEach(...` inside of the interval. In this case its not very intensive, but it could be when handling many more elements. In any ways it does not make a lot of sense to search for the same elements every second when they never change. You'd just be assigning the same value over and over. So *saving* them once and using the *reference* to them later on in the code will make your code cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks for your effort! I will try to implement this